# Deployment of build Artifact (War files) to different environments (Dev, test, Prod) using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are able to build Java applications whenever the developer checkin the code into code repository using jenkins and the generated war file is auto deployed to a dev environment (Tomcat server). 
Later we need to deploy the same war file to a test environment. Is there any feature in jenkins which deploys the war file from the dev to test environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider setting up an artifact repository (Nexus, Artifactory), where you store your Artifacts. Then your deployments should always take the artifacts from this repository.

To perform a deployment from Nexus you could use the deploy plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend publishing the WAR file into a Maven repository, like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), and then use [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) to perform the deployments.

Rundeck has plugins for both [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin) and [Nexus](https://github.com/vbehar/nexus-rundeck-plugin)